# MATLAB performance benefit from clearing temporary variables?

Tags: performance, matlab, temp-tables

MATLAB has an annoying feature of sometimes requiring you to create temporary variables, e.g. `temporary_variable`, in order to create something to be used in another variable, after which the temporary variable is not used anywhere else in the code. Is there a performance benefit to using `clear temporary_variable` after the temporary variable has done its job? What the most performance efficient way of handling this kind of situation? Thanks for your insight!

Comment: I tend to delete them for clarity (remove clutter) and for safety (prevent accidental access to a variable that simply shouldn't exist). It would be interesting to know if performance is impacted, though. Interesting question

Comment: It is a good practice to delete them, as they take up some memory (although not a lot), Also, if you are using IDE or some Matlab-Java interface, this will be picked up by the Garbage Collector, which could cause JVM to blow up if it is too big. It is a good practice, but I do not think it will affect your code running for almost all of the situations.

Comment: Maybe. But it might also force MATLAB to perform a deep copy on the array that it had previously created a header for. It all depends on the situation. How many thousands of these temporary variables are you creating, and how many megabytes of RAM do each of them occupy?

Comment: Well, I actually just created one temporary variable for my current program so it's negligible, but it just got me thinking on what would be general good practice.

Comment: Personally, I don't find temp variables as distasteful as some. The main problem comes when you no longer have sufficient RAM to allocate contiguous memory for your arrays. (There's also the issue of too many variables cluttering your workspace, but that's a different problem entirely.)  Have you looked at this yet? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html

Comment: Didn't see that doc before, but thanks for pointing it out! Will read it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Several comments:

1. Unless you're running out of memory, clearing variables almost certainly won't help performance.
2. In my experience, the problem with a proliferation of temporary variables is its contribution to programming mistakes. Eg. you have a typo, writing `x` instead of `X` but your code doesn't immediately throw an error because you defined an `x` previously.
3. That said, I almost never bother to clear temporary variables during a MATLAB script.

#### Tips to keep workspace clean (mostly to help reduce coding errors)

1. Use the `clear` command at the start of a script. (This reduces [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) problems where code works or doesn't work depending on what you did before running the script...)
2. Put much/most of your code in user defined [functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html). Variables local to a function automatically go out of scope (i.e. disappear) once the function ends, and within a function, you can't mistakenly access variables in your workspace that you shouldn't be accessing.

Comment: Tip 2 is actually the most important one.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is good practice to avoid creating temporary variables in case they are too large. I guess I do not really need to elaborate on why it is bad. In most cases there are alternatives that does not require temporary variables. In case temporary variables are still needed they are in many cases used just once. In that case you can merge the expressions you need to write into a single expression (in case it does not get to messy)

```
a = 1:10;
b = a(a>5);
```

This will still create this temporary variable, but you will not have to clear it. Matlab does this cleanup itself. However, in case tempoary becomes a problem it is most likely due to design problems or too large functions. The only problem I have noticed with large memory consumption is memory problem. My experience is that the more information you store in memory, the faster the program executes. It takes a lot of time to recalculate some things. However, in most cases there is a trade-off between memory efficiency and processing efficiency.